# Jquery Mobile pop up not working

Tags: jquery-mobile

When I click on the pop up link it turns blue but nothing popup. I would like to know what I am doing wrong. Do I need to refresh the navbar? I know that jquery mobile events need to be refreshed. Should I use the listview('refresh') ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Customer Chooses Beer Quantity</title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.3/jquery.mobile.min.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.3/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>
    <script>                                                  
    $(document).on('pagebeforeshow','#index', function(){

    start_beer_quantity_from_0();

    //hide the ui loader
     $("#index").loader().loader("option", "disabled", true );

                                //ajax call to beers


    function start_beer_quantity_from_0(){  
                                        //form variables
                                        var beer_count  = 0;
                                        var formData    = {beer_count:beer_count};

                                        ajax_update_content_when_page_is_loaded_beer_quantity(formData);
                                       }                            

     function ajax_update_content_when_page_is_loaded_beer_quantity(formData){

    $.ajax({


                                                               url     : '<?php echo base_url()."index.php/drink_cart/customer_chooses_beer_quantity"; ?>',
                                                               async   : true,
                                                               type    : "POST",
                                                               cache   : false,
                                                               data    : formData,
                                                               dataType: "html",                                                             
                                                               success : function(data){

                                                                             //alert($.trim(data));
                                                                             $('.display_beer_count').html(data);                                                                           

                                                                     },
                                                       error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                                                                                 $('#server_message_error_jqXHR').html("here is the jqXHR"+jqXHR);
                                                                                 $('#server_message_error_textStatus').html("here is the textStatus "+textStatus);
                                                                                 $('#server_message_error_errorThrown').html("here is the errorThrown"+errorThrown);
                                                                                         } 


                });     
        return false;
                                                                          }


       });

    $(document).on('click','.beers', function (event){

                                          var beer_quantity      = $(this).find(".beer_quantity").val();
                                          var beer               = $(this).find(".beer").val();

                            //form variables
                            var formData = {
                                            beer_quantity:beer_quantity,beer:beer
                                           }; 
                                submit_ajax_form_add_beer(formData);                                                

    event.preventDefault();

    function submit_ajax_form_add_beer(formData){

        $.ajax({


                                                               url     : '<?php echo base_url()."index.php/drink_cart/customer_chooses_beer_quantity"; ?>',
                                                               async   : true,
                                                               type    : "POST",
                                                               cache   : false,
                                                               data    : formData,
                                                               dataType: "html",                                                             
                                                               success : function(data){                                                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                          // alert("Beer posted");
                                                                                          $('.display_beer_count').html($.trim(data));                                                                            
                                                                                        },

                                                       error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                                                                                 alert("There is not internet connection. Please check your internet connection");

                                                                                 $('#server_message_error_jqXHR').html("here is the jqXHR"+jqXHR);
                                                                                 $('#server_message_error_textStatus').html("here is the textStatus "+textStatus);
                                                                                 $('#server_message_error_errorThrown').html("here is the errorThrown"+errorThrown);
                                                                                         } 

                }); 
                 return false;  


                                             }  

                                              });        


    </script>  
    </head>
    <body >
    <div data-role="page" id="index" >    
          <div data-role="popup" id="settings_popup_beer_quantity" data-position="right">       
        <ul data-inset="true" data-role="listview" data-theme="a" data-divider-theme="b" style="min-width:210px;">
                   <li data-role="list-divider">Settings</li>
                   <li data-icon="false"><?php echo anchor('login/logout/','Logout',       array('title'=>"Logout",  "rel" =>"external"));?></li>
                   <li data-icon="false"><?php echo anchor('customer_settings/','Settings',array('title'=>"Settings","rel" =>"external"));?></li></ul></div>
    <div style="float:left;">
                            <img class="small_logo" border="0" src="<?php echo $this->config->base_url();?>images/small_logo.png"  alt="cup Bar Express" />
                            </div>
    <div data-role="header" style="width:100px;float:right;" data-position="right">
        <div class="settings_button_quantity" data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#settings_popup_beer_quantity" data-rel="popup"  data-transition="pop" class="settings_popup_link_quantity ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-corner-all ui-shadow  ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-bars">Settings</a></li>         
            </ul>
            </div>
            </div>
      <div style="clear:both;"></div>                                                       
       <div role="main" class="ui-content"  id="index">
            <div class="background_image">      
        <div class="ui-grid-solo" id="title">QUANTITY</div> 
            <ul  data-role="listview" data-split-theme="a" data-inset="true">
    <?php 
    if(isset($beer_quantity_button)){
                                     echo $beer_quantity_button;
                                     }
    ?>
            </ul>
            </div>
        </div> 

    <style type="text/css">  
    .ui-listview>li h1, .ui-listview>li h2, .ui-listview>li h3, .ui-listview>li h4, .ui-listview>li h5, .ui-listview>li h6{
                                                                                                                           font-family:'RNS Camelia';
                                                                                                                           text-shadow: none;
                                                                                                                           color      : black !important;
                                                                                                                           font-weight: 700;
                                                                                                                           font-size  : 33px;   
                                                                                                                           }

    li h1 .display_beer_count{
                              color:white;
                             } 

    .ui-listview>.ui-li-static, .ui-listview>.ui-li-divider, .ui-listview>li>a.ui-btn{                                                                         
                                                                                       padding-right:18px;
                                                                                       padding-left :18px;
                                                                                       text-align   :center;
                                                                                       background   :transparent !important;
                                                                                      }
    button.ui-btn.beer_quantity_button{
                                       border    :none;
                                       color     : black      !important;
                                       background: #D6DE23    !important;
                                      }

    .ui-listview>li h1.add_beer_to_cart_letters {
                                                  color:white !important;
                                                  }

    button.add_beer_to_cart {
                              background: transparent !important;   
                            }

    @font-face {
                font-family:'RNS Camelia';
                font-style : normal;
                font-weight: 900;
                src        : local('RNS Camelia'), url(<?php echo $this->config->base_url();?>fonts/RNS_Camelia.otf);
               }

    @font-face{
                font-family:'Simply City Light';
                font-style : normal;
                font-weight: normal;
                src        : local('Simply City Light'), url(<?php echo $this->config->base_url();?>fonts/siml023.ttf);
               }

    .settings_button_quantity{
                              width     :100px; 
                              height    :22px; 
                              float     :right;
                             }

    a .settings_popup_link_quantity{
                                   height:22px;
                                   }


    .ui-content .ui-listview-inset, .ui-panel-inner>.ui-listview-inset{
                                                                        margin:0;
                                                                       }

    #title{ 
           text-shadow  : none!important;
           margin-bottom: 11px;
           width        : 100%;
           font-size    : 52px                !important;
           font-family  :'RNS Camelia'        !important;            
           color        : #D6DE23             !important;   
           padding-left : 5%;
          }

    .background_image{
                      width         :100%  !important;
                      padding-bottom:160px !important;
                      margin-left   :auto  !important;
                      margin-right  :auto  !important;
                      display       :block;             
                      background    :url(<?php echo $this->config->base_url();?>images/beer_cup.png) no-repeat;               
                      z-index       :-21;
                     }

    .ui-page{
             background-image :url('<?php echo $this->config->base_url();?>images/background.png') !important;
             width            :100%;
             background-size  :100% 100%;
             background-repeat:no-repeat;
             } 

    .small_logo{
                padding-top: 4px;
                width      : 138px;
                height     : 52px;
               } 

    #settings_popup_beer_quantity li a,#settings_popup_beer_quantity,.ui-navbar li:last-child .ui-btn {
                                                                                                       color      :black              !important;
                                                                                                       font-family:'Simply City Light'!important;
                                                                                                       }  
    #settings_popup_beer_quantity .ui-li-divider{
                                                 background:black!important;
                                                 }           
        </style>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I copied your code into a fiddle here and it appears to be working for me. at least the popup shows up when I click the link.

https://jsfiddle.net/2y9ouhzb/

```
<div data-role="page" id="index">
    <div data-role="popup" id="settings_popup_beer_quantity" data-position="right">
        <ul data-inset="true" data-role="listview" data-theme="a" data-divider-theme="b" style="min-width:210px;">
            <li data-role="list-divider">Settings</li>
            <li data-icon="false">
                <?php echo anchor( 'login/logout/', 'Logout', array( 'title'=>"Logout", "rel" =>"external"));?></li>
            <li data-icon="false">
                <?php echo anchor( 'customer_settings/', 'Settings',array( 'title'=>"Settings","rel" =>"external"));?></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div style="float:left;">
        <img class="small_logo" border="0" src="<?php echo $this->config->base_url();?>images/small_logo.png" alt="cup Bar Express" />
    </div>
    <div data-role="header" style="width:100px;float:right;" data-position="right">
        <div class="settings_button_quantity" data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#settings_popup_beer_quantity" data-rel="popup" data-transition="pop" class="settings_popup_link_quantity ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-corner-all ui-shadow  ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-bars">Settings</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    <div role="main" class="ui-content" id="index">
        <div class="background_image">
            <div class="ui-grid-solo" id="title">QUANTITY</div>
            <ul data-role="listview" data-split-theme="a" data-inset="true">
                <?php if(isset($beer_quantity_button)){ echo $beer_quantity_button; } ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /page -->
```

Comment: I think the ajax function "start_beer_quantity_from_0();" was freezing the DOM